# Cannot select from multiple tables when also using JOIN

Tags: sql, select, join

Here is the working query:

```
$sql_project_data = "SELECT P.project_id, P.project_name, P.project_type, 
                    F.professor_first_name, F.professor_last_name, C.course_id
                    FROM sl_student_course S
                    INNER JOIN sl_course C 
                        ON C.course_id = S.course_id
                    INNER JOIN sl_professor F 
                        ON F.professor_id = C.professor_id
                    INNER JOIN sl_project_course PC 
                        ON PC.course_id = C.course_id
                    INNER JOIN sl_project P 
                        ON P.project_id = PC.project_id
                    WHERE S.student_id = '" . $_SESSION['user_id'] . "'";
```

I want to add a condition in the where clause saying "sl_project_course_student.project_id<> 33" - However, when I try to do this, the query stops working (columns which were once recognized in the original query are no longer being recognized).

```
$sql_project_data = "SELECT P.project_id, P.project_name, P.project_type, 
                        F.professor_first_name, F.professor_last_name, C.course_id, 
                        G.project_id
                    FROM sl_student_course S, sl_project_course_student G
                    INNER JOIN sl_course C 
                        ON C.course_id = S.course_id
                    INNER JOIN sl_professor F 
                        ON F.professor_id = C.professor_id
                    INNER JOIN sl_project_course PC 
                        ON PC.course_id = C.course_id
                    INNER JOIN sl_project P 
                        ON P.project_id = PC.project_id
                    WHERE S.student_id = '" . $_SESSION['user_id'] . "' 
                        AND G.project_id <> 33";
```

Notice, I'm selecting the second table after "From" and I added "And" to the where clause.

I'm assuming the syntax is wrong, how should I change this so that it will be syntactically correct?

Comment: I don't see how your first query is working you reference G.project_id but you have no tables with an alias of G.

Comment: @bluefeet Sorry, the first query should not have had that - removed it. Error while copying over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second query is missing `JOIN` syntax for the table `sl_project_course_student`. Based on the fact you are are trying to add G.project_id it looks like you will JOIN that with the table `sl_project`

```
$sql_project_data = "SELECT P.project_id, P.project_name, P.project_type, 
                        F.professor_first_name, F.professor_last_name, C.course_id, 
                        G.project_id
                    FROM sl_student_course S, sl_project_course_student G
                    INNER JOIN sl_course C 
                        ON C.course_id = S.course_id
                    INNER JOIN sl_professor F 
                        ON F.professor_id = C.professor_id
                    INNER JOIN sl_project_course PC 
                        ON PC.course_id = C.course_id
                    INNER JOIN sl_project P 
                        ON P.project_id = PC.project_id
                    LEFT JOIN sl_project_course_student G
                        ON P.project_id = G.project_id
                    WHERE S.student_id = '" . $_SESSION['user_id'] . "' 
                        AND G.project_id <> 33";
```

Here is a helpful link on the [visual explanation of joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Based on the fact you said you are looking for those items not in the sl_project_course_student table you might need this:

```
$sql_project_data = "SELECT P.project_id, P.project_name, P.project_type, 
                        F.professor_first_name, F.professor_last_name, C.course_id, 
                        G.project_id
                    FROM sl_student_course S, sl_project_course_student G
                    INNER JOIN sl_course C 
                        ON C.course_id = S.course_id
                    INNER JOIN sl_professor F 
                        ON F.professor_id = C.professor_id
                    INNER JOIN sl_project_course PC 
                        ON PC.course_id = C.course_id
                    INNER JOIN sl_project P 
                        ON P.project_id = PC.project_id
                    LEFT JOIN sl_project_course_student G
                        ON P.project_id = G.project_id
                    WHERE S.student_id = '" . $_SESSION['user_id'] . "' 
                        AND G.project_id Is Null;
```

Comment: The problem with this is, if the project_id is not found in product_course_student table, I want the row to be returned. With this code, if the row is not in that table, it's not being returned.

Comment: can you post some sample data?

Comment: a few questions 1) you are looking for projects not in the sl_projct_course_student table correct?  2) but then you are specifically asking for the project_id not equal to 33.  is that the correct logic?

Comment: There are two types of projects, 1) Completed, 2) Pending. If the project is in the `sl_project_course_student` table, that means the project is Completed and I therefore do not want to display that data. That is why I say "Where project_Id <> 33"

Answer (score 0):

in the second query you have added a new table:

```
sl_project_course_student G
```

in the from list without joining it to any other table... what if you join it to the corresponding table(s)?

Comment: That would work, in theory, however I only want to return rows when they are NOT present in sl_project_course_student. So, I don't think joining would work, right?

Comment: then you have to add a subquery with a "and not exists (select ... from sl_project_course_student where ...)" If you simply leave a table in the middle of nowhere it won't do anything

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql_project_data = "SELECT P.project_id, P.project_name, P.project_type, F.professor_first_name, F.professor_last_name, C.course_id, G.project_id
                        FROM sl_student_course S
                            INNER JOIN sl_course C ON C.course_id = S.course_id
                            INNER JOIN sl_professor F ON F.professor_id = C.professor_id
                            INNER JOIN sl_project_course PC ON PC.course_id = C.course_id
                            INNER JOIN sl_project P ON P.project_id = PC.project_id
                            LEFT JOIN sl_project_course_student G ON P.project_id = G.project_id AND C.course_id = G.course_id AND S.student_id = G.student_id
                        WHERE S.student_id = '" . $_SESSION['user_id'] . "' AND IFNULL(G.project_id, 33) <> 33)";
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the "left" join here? I will read on it, but I don't have much luck learning about joins from the articles I've read.

Comment: @Evan, try [reading this](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).